# Create page template

Tags: pages, page-template

I am completely new to working in Wordpress but have some skills in coding. My company has a website where we write about different publicly traded companies. I want to add company specific pages to the website. All the pages should look identical but contain information about the particular company that is viewed. I want to be able to create a template which can the be used for all companies. I want the urls to be mysite.com/company1, mysite.com/company2 and so on. I am sure this is an easy thing to do but I am so new to Wordpress that I do not even know what to search for to read about this. I would greatly appreciate if someone could provide some help and push me in the right direction.

Thank you!

Comment: What you're describing is a good use case for Custom Post Types. There's developer (i.e. coding) documentation on creating them here: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/post-types/registering-custom-post-types/ But if you're not a developer then there's plugins available for creating them. Just knowing the term "custom post type" should help you find a lot more resources on what you need though.

Answer (score 0):

you must create a template in theme root directory like below and create a new page in wordpress admin dashboard and choose template from right menu like image below:

my-page-template.php:

```
<?php /* Template Name: MyTpl_1 */ ?>

<?php
    // your logic goes here ...
?>
```

and choose it from menu while creating a new page:
[image]

Comment: Template can be create under templates folder of the theme. So it is not mandatory to create the templates to the root of the themes. You can have your own choice. WordPress is always look for the Annotation tag of the page templates to detect as Page Templates.